Least-cost paths observing maximum slope level in QGIS
Another inquiry as concerns my comeback geofictional project.
Over the past several days, I've returned to making use of QGIS' tools for least-cost paths (at least on version 3.30, after experimenting with them on 2.18 several years ago). Last weekend's challenge: Generating highways as long as they do not exceed a maximum slope-percentage limit, in my case 5% (1:20). (As recommended by a Quora user several years ago; U.S. federal limits are slightly higher, with 6% allotted in mountainous/hilly areas and 7% in cases where the speed limit is lower than 60 mph.)
And for a good reason: In my "study area" (a term others prefer to use), there are no contiguous (i.e. continuous without a break) stretches of land below 5%, not helped by the fact that it's highly volcanic in origin. Said stretches, some of them confined to the coast, only last as far as several kilometres at best before higher slopes come in. To my credit, I've tried out several dozen Raster Calculator combinations so far (involving slope values/levels, aspect, geomorphons, curvature, the Topographic Wetness Index [TWI]--the list goes on), and even installed the Least Cost Path plugin as an experiment, but the best attempts either take the roads over rivers (which no one wants), or violate the maximum limit.
Preferably, I'd like to see segments that run parallel to the slope, i.e. on the same contour line or close to it, à la best practices in real-world road engineering. This is related to the cut-and-fill and full-benched processes, an example of which is provided on ResearchGate. (Now I know what that technique is--but then again, the same applied for "corniche" a few days prior.)
I've done a lot of research on the topic during this testing period, and similar questions have cropped up on GIS.SE and elsewhere for the past decade. (Note that a good deal of this coverage deals with non-QGIS procedures).

Qgis Least Cost Path with certain threshold (from May 2017; no responses yet. Let's hope mine doesn't go the same path [to pardon a pun].)
Finding least cost path in QGIS? (September 2016; closed)

Road design using Least cost path by longitudinal slope in ArcGIS Desktop? (2017; algorithm provided in answer is private)


A path with slopes on the terrain (April 2023; for Rhinoceros Grasshopper users; links to...)

Path Finder Using a Recursive Process - Example 8.5 (February 17, 2015; this is the process I'd like to emulate in QGIS)


Least Cost Path Analysis (October/November 2020 slideshow; mentions something called the "ox-cart slope" on page 13, with a formula of f(s) = 1+(s/c)^2 [where s represents the slope map and c the critical slope])

And last but not least--and most importantly...

Connect two contour lines with calculated line length (January 2015; mentions PEGGER, a vintage ArcGIS plugin. PEGGER calculates roads by this algorithm: d = i / (G / 100), where d is the distance segment; i, the vertical interval between contours; and G, the percentage of the desired slope. The Forest Road Designer plugin is the closest equivalent in QGIS, but requires the SciPy library; has a Spanish-only manual and UI; and received its most recent update last August. A while afterward, GitHub user "Xadamo" reported that it might not load on recent versions of QGIS, and may cause the program itself to crash. If you're reading this as one of its users, please let me know otherwise.)

Wish I could place a bounty on this thing, because it sure deserves one. Can anyone point to/devise the best solution for this scenario (preferably within five to seven days)?
To help you along, here's the same DEM from last time. More shapefiles/rasters to come as needed.

@Bera: Already went through that--and even so, the Least Cost Path plugin made a few undesirable diversions when inspecting my completed cost layer a few days ago. As I am making clear, the areas with less than 5% are spotty at best, largely interrupted by the surrounding high-slope terrain.

@Bera: By "undesirable diversions", I mean segments that go higher than 5%.

@Bera: Tried that tip hours ago; sorry for the late reply. Still doesn't work; violations still persist. From here, maybe we could bring in someone who knows both ArcGIS and QGIS to work on either a stable rewrite of PEGGER/FRD for the latter or an equivalent (Python) script?
